# csv import neo4j . how to refer the node outside foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

below is the cypher import script

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
CREATE (transaction:Transaction{trxid:TOINT(line.COMBINED)})
MERGE (party:Party{partyname:UPPER(line.OPARTY)})
FOREACH (bnk1 IN (CASE WHEN line.BANK_ID_1 IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [line.BANK_ID_1] END) |
MERGE (bank1:Bank{bankname:bnk1})
//relation
MERGE (transaction)-[:Trough]->(bank1)
)
FOREACH (bnk2 IN (CASE WHEN line.BANK_ID_2 is NULL THEN [] ELSE [line.BANK_ID_2] END) |
MERGE (bank2:Bank{bankname:bnk2})
//relation
)
FOREACH (bnk3 IN (CASE  WHEN line.BANK_ID_3  is NULL THEN  [] ELSE [line.BANK_ID_3] END) |
MERGE (bank3:Bank{bankname:bnk3})
//relation
MERGE (bank2)-[:next]->(bank3)
)
MERGE (party)-[:Initiated]->(transaction)

MERGE (transaction)-[:Trough]->(bank1)
MERGE(bank1)-[:next]->(bank2)
MERGE (bank2)-[:next]->(bank3)
```

I am trying to create the relationship between bank1 and bank2 .am not able to create since bank1 and bank2 nodes are created inside the foreach . pls help in solving this

sample.csv
COMBINED,OPARTY,BANK_ID_1,BANK_ID_2,BANK_ID_3
1,arun,boa,axis,
2,reddy,ml,,icici

I want the result in

```
reddy->2->ml->[]->icici
```

here reddy initiated the trx 2 thru ml bank and then to empty bank and finally to icici

```
arun ->1->boa->axis->[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to go about it.  You could pass the array through with `WITH` and then `UNWIND` it like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
CREATE (transaction:Transaction{trxid:TOINT(line.COMBINED)})
MERGE (party:Party{partyname:UPPER(line.OPARTY)})
WITH (CASE WHEN line.BANK_ID_1 IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [line.BANK_ID_1] END) AS bank_ids_1
UNWIND bank_ids_1 and bank_id_1
MERGE (bank1:Bank{bankname:bank_id_1})
```

Or you could go through the CSV multiple times:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
CREATE (transaction:Transaction {trxid:TOINT(line.COMBINED)});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
WHERE NOT(line.BANK_ID_1 IS NULL)
MERGE (:Bank{bankname:line.BANK_ID_1});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
WHERE NOT(line.BANK_ID_2 IS NULL)
MERGE (:Bank{bankname:line.BANK_ID_2});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'sample.csv' AS line
WHERE NOT(line.BANK_ID_1 IS NULL) AND NOT(line.BANK_ID_2 IS NULL)
MATCH
  (bank1:Bank{bankname:line.BANK_ID_1}),
  (bank2:Bank{bankname:line.BANK_ID_2})
MERGE(bank1)-[:next]->(bank2);
```

etc...  This is a rough example, of course.

Personally I like the second option for it's understandability.